# Vector value after normalization

Tags: linear-algebra, modules, vectors

I have started to learn the theory of vectors in linear algebra and have some beginner question.

I'm reading about vector normalization, that any normalized vector is becoming the unit one (which magnitude equals `1.0` ). I'm confused with the next thing:

Let's define a new 2D-vector:

$$a=
\left(
\begin{matrix}
5\\
7\\ 
\end{matrix}
\right)$$

As I understood the normalization equals:

$$\text{normalized}(a) = \frac{a}{|a|}$$

Where |a| is a magnitude ( module ) of vector, which calculates for 2D case, by the next formula:

$$|a| = \sqrt{ a_x^2 + a_y^2 }$$

So, if to repeat these steps for the vector which is defined above:

$$|a| = \sqrt{ 5^2 + 7^2 } = \sqrt{ 25 + 49 } = 8.6$$

$$
\text{normalized}(a)=\frac{a}{|a|} =
\frac{\left(
\begin{matrix}
5\\
7\\ 
\end{matrix}
\right)}{ 8.6}
    = \left(
\begin{matrix}
\frac{5} {8.6}\\
\frac{7}  {8.6 }\end{matrix}
\right)
= \left(
\begin{matrix}
0.581\\
0.814 \end{matrix}
\right)
$$

So, I've got the final normalized vector, be the read theory any normalized vector is the unit one, so its magnitude must be equal `1.0`.

Let's check:

$$
\begin{aligned}
|normalized(a)| &= \sqrt{ normalized(a)_x^2 + normalized(a)_y^2 }\\
    &= \sqrt{ 0.581^2 + 0.814^2 }\\
    &= \sqrt{ 0.337561 + 0.662596 }\\
    &= \sqrt{ 1.000157 }\\
    &= 1.0000784969191168445817798216141\\
\end{aligned}
$$

So... The next questions are:

- Is the theory which I have read the correct one? Is really any normalized vector the unit one?
- Must really the magnitude of any unit vector be really 1.0 or it's allowed to have some thousandths values in residue of magnitude value?

Comment: You have rounded the length of a vector $a$ to a single decimal place!

Comment: as mentioned in the answers this is a rounding Error. If you work with Computers or in Physics this is ok but in Mathematics you would rather not round and stick to the true Value wich is as mentiond below $\sqrt{74}$ so the normalized vector would be $\left(\frac{5}{\sqrt{74}},\frac{7}{\sqrt{74}}\right)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A normalized vector has *unit* norm, that's the definition of being normalized, and it also follows from your definition. Let's check (in symbols): 
$$ \def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}\abs{\def\n{\mathord{\rm normalized}}\n(a)} = \sqrt{\n(a).x^2 + \n(a).y^2} = \sqrt{\frac{a.x^2}{\abs a^2} + \frac{a.y^2}{\abs a^2}} = \sqrt{\frac{a.x^2 + a.y^2}{\abs a^2}} = 1 $$
The problem in your example is that during your calculations you made rounding errors. The norm of the given vector is not $8.6$, it's $\sqrt{74}$, which is an irrational number, which cannot be written in a finite decimal expansion.

Answer (score 1):

A normalized vector (more commonly known as a unit vector) has norm 1.

The reason why you don't have exactly one is that you're using finite precision on a computer ($\sqrt{25+49}$ isn't 8.6. It's $8.6023252670...$).